# how to count and remove similar strings across columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data with many columns . for example this is with three columns

```
df<-structure(list(V1 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L
), .Label = c("CPSIAAAIAAVNALHGR", "DLNYCFSGMSDHR", "FPEHELIVDPQR", 
"IADPDAVKPDDWDEDAPSK", "LWADHGVQACFGR", "WGEAGAEYVVESTGVFTTMEK", 
"YYVTIIDAPGHR"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(5L, 2L, 
7L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "CPSIAAAIAAVNALHGR", 
"GCITIIGGGDTATCCAK", "HVGPGVLSMANAGPNTNGSQFFICTIK", "LLELGPKPEVAQQTR", 
"MVCCSAWSEDHPICNLFTCGFDR", "YYVTIIDAPGHR"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "AVCMLSNTTAIAEAWAR", "DLNYCFSGMSDHR", "FPEHELIVDPQR"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

-The first column, we don't look at any other column, we just count how many strings there are and keep the unique one

- The second column, we keep the unique and also we remove those that were already in the first column
- The third column, we keep the unique and we remove the strings that were in the first and second column

This continues for as many columns as we have

for example for this data, we will have the following

```
 Column 1              Column 2                    Column 3
LWADHGVQACFGR
CPSIAAAIAAVNALHGR     LLELGPKPEVAQQTR              AVCMLSNTTAIAEAWAR
YYVTIIDAPGHR          GCITIIGGGDTATCCAK 
FPEHELIVDPQR          HVGPGVLSMANAGPNTNGSQFFICTIK   
DLNYCFSGMSDHR         MVCCSAWSEDHPICNLFTCGFDR   
IADPDAVKPDDWDEDAPSK     
WGEAGAEYVVESTGVFTTMEK
```

Comment: sorry, I must have misread the question

Comment: @akrun if you know any solution, I will be happy to accept it

Comment: I am a bit busy at the moment with some models running

Comment: Are you positive your result is correct and reflecting your example?

Comment: @Sotos Yes I think the result is correct

Comment: Why `LWADHGVQACFGR` (`df[1, 1]`) is removed? I think it is unique in the `V1` column.

Comment: @ycw you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution via `tidyverse`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
 gather(var, string) %>% 
 filter(string != '' & !duplicated(string)) %>% 
 group_by(var) %>% 
 mutate(cnt = seq(n())) %>% 
 spread(var, string) %>%
 select(-cnt)
```

Which gives

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 4
>     cnt                    V1                          V2                V3
> * <int>                 <chr>                       <chr>             <chr>
> 1     1         LWADHGVQACFGR             LLELGPKPEVAQQTR AVCMLSNTTAIAEAWAR
> 2     2     CPSIAAAIAAVNALHGR           GCITIIGGGDTATCCAK              <NA>
> 3     3          YYVTIIDAPGHR HVGPGVLSMANAGPNTNGSQFFICTIK              <NA>
> 4     4          FPEHELIVDPQR     MVCCSAWSEDHPICNLFTCGFDR              <NA>
> 5     5         DLNYCFSGMSDHR                        <NA>              <NA>
> 6     6   IADPDAVKPDDWDEDAPSK                        <NA>              <NA>
> 7     7 WGEAGAEYVVESTGVFTTMEK                        <NA>              <NA>
> ```

You can use `colSums` to get the number of strings,

```
colSums(!is.na(df1))
#V1 V2 V3 
# 7  4  1
```

A similar approach via base R, that would save the strings in a list would be,

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
d1 <- stack(df)
d1 <- d1[d1$values != '' & !duplicated(d1$values),]
l1 <- unstack(d1, values ~ ind)

lengths(l1)
#V1 V2 V3 
# 7  4  1
```

Comment: can you add the number of strings per each column instead <chr> on top of each column?

Comment: What do you mean? <chr> is just how the data frame is displayed in the console. You mean to add another row at the top with the number of of strings (7, 4, 1)?

Comment: I got this error `Error in select(-cnt) : object 'cnt' not found`

Comment: Small typo on my part. Try it again

Comment: two more requests. 1- can you please add some explanation so that i learn what you did? 2- when I do this `colSums(!is.na(df1))` it will make the column report randomly, how can I print the column with the same order as they are (like the `lengths(l1)`)

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution. `df2` is the final output.

```
# Convert to character
L1 <- lapply(df, as.character)
# Get unique string
L2 <- lapply(L1, unique)
# Remove ""
L3 <- lapply(L2, function(vec){vec <- vec[!(vec %in% "")]})

# Use for loop to remove non-unique string from previous columns
for (i in 2:length(L3)){
  previous_vec <- unlist(L3[1:(i - 1)])
  current_vec <- L3[[i]]
  L3[[i]] <- current_vec[!(current_vec %in% previous_vec)]
}

# Get the maximum column length
max_num <- max(sapply(L3, length))

# Append "" to each column
L4 <- lapply(L3, function(vec){vec <- c(vec, rep("", max_num - length(vec)))})

# Convert L4 to a data frame
df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, L4))
```

Comment: I liked your answer